# How to require a specific file in application.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to require "font-awesome.scss" in the application.css of my Rails 4 app like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets,    vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require 'font-awesome.scss'
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

'font-awesome.scss' imports a bunch of files that look like partials, with a preceding underscore. One of these partials (_variables.scss) defines a variable that I need to define as of the moment I get the following error message:

```
Sass::SyntaxError (Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".
(in /Users/bla/rails_projects/Homepage/app/assets/stylesheets/_bordered-pulled.scss:4)):
app/assets/stylesheets/_bordered-pulled.scss:4
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:35:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3531690645719711557_70221015865520'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried requiring font-awesome after tree and self? . Bootstrap is similar to foundation, and my foundation files are always required after tree and self to appropriately get imported into the asset pipeline. Plus, you would want your own CSS to override font-awesome if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
*= require font-awesome
```

No need to put the quotes or extension.
More docs on the subject here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks Nick. But I tried that already. How will Rails know which font-awesome to require? In the folder are font-awesome.css. font-awesome.min.css and font-awesome.scss

Comment: Are you using the font-awesome gem? If so, this should do the trick. If not, let me know and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: You cannot require a scss file you have to use @import

Answer (score 0):

you can use font awesome without the gem, just use their cdn.

This goes in your layout, application.html.erb

```
<head>
...
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
</head>
```

More info here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

Try checking how you are precompiling assets. Check initializers/assets.rb (or it may be environments/production.rb for you) to make sure you are precompiling assets in a friendly way, like this:

```
config.assets.precompile += ["*.js", "*.scss", "*.jpg", "*.png"]
```

I was having this same error when it was

```
config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.png/,/.*\.ico/,/.*\.jpg/,/.*\.js/,/.*\.scss/]
```